# How can we know that how many nodes we need inside a Replicaset?

Tags: mongodb

Currently we are using `Primary Slave Setup` for our current MongoDB Production Servers .

We are expected to have more load on our MongoDB as there would be more number of users would be added to our Site .

I see that `Mongo Master Slave is deprecated` , and the best approach is to use `MongoDB Replicasets` .

The only limitaion (as far as i know) i see  with replication is that

**" We can have a maximum of 12 nodes in a set " and in case if you need more go for Sharding ."**

My question is that ,

**How can we know how do we know how many nodes we need ??**

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact answer to your question, but considering following factors can be useful:

1. the volume of data you need to store
2. average load on your server
3. the peak load on your server
4. what is the application access patters
5. total number of indexes you have / need
6. what is the percent of queries that can be processed using indexes.
7. willingness to read from secondaries.

You can run benchmarking based on some dummy data and figure out the the best solution for your use case. Hope this helps!